# php array push adding that data in other code block

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

i want to array push some data to my main array. but it add my push data incorrectly. i have below code.

```
$customKeyboard = array();
$customKeyboard = [
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [["text" => "back ", "callback_data" => "back"]]
    ]
];
```

then I do this

```
$customKeyboard[] = [["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]];
```

and i want to $customKeyboard[] data will result as below

```
$customKeyboard = [
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [["text" => "back ", "callback_data" => "back"]],
        [["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]]
    ]
];
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to `inline_keyboard` in the "then I do this" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly tell the system under what level / hierarchy you want to add the new data

So , change the line

```
$customKeyboard[] = [["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]];
```

to

```
$customKeyboard["inline_keyboard"][] = [["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]];
```

So, use the following

```
<?php
$customKeyboard = array();
$customKeyboard = [
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [["text" => "back ", "callback_data" => "back"]]
    ]
];

$customKeyboard["inline_keyboard"][] = [["text" => "test", "callback_data" => "test"]];
?>
```

See [Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/c5d65)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works now. But I still have a problem, I want to push the data to $customKeyboard before ""back ", i.e. I want the ""back " button to be shown below all input data.

Comment: Please post a new question for this. Thanks